# How to pass parameter in the Cucumber Runner file to run files from specific folder

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, build.gradle, cucumber-jvm

I am using Serenity Cucumber framework using Gradle. I have integrated this with Jenkins. My requirement is that as a part of one Jenkins job I would like to run the feature files from one folder and as a part of next Jenkins job feature files located from other folder should get executed. Can you please suggest how I can pass the parameters to Cucumber Runner file during run time. For e.g.:
Below is my feature file

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/Sanity/")
public class TestRunnerSerenity {
}
```

As a part of Sanity Build all my test cases from src/test/resources/Sanity/ folder should get executed. So how I can pass this folder path value to the Cucumber Runner class run time. So that I can maintain my builds without having multiple runner files and manual intervention.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have you thought about a second runner class with the config you need? when you specifiy tags for each, then each runner executes only the features it should execute.

Answer (score 0):

There is some configuration need to do in Code,Gradle and Jenkins and Here is step by step

In Grade file, I will create systemProperty function.

```
        task prodTest(type: Test)
        prodTest{
             systemProperty 'test.folder', testFolder  
     }

   task "runProdTest" {
    dependsOn "clean", "cleanTest", "prodTest"
}
```

In Constants Class, 
Create static final String

```
public static final String TEST_FOLDER = system.getProperty("test.folder","FolderName")`
```

When you run locally, It will not failed because of external parameter is not available.

Go to runner file,

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = Constants.TEST_FOLDER)
public class TestRunnerSerenity {
}
```

Now Jenkins Configuration

```
Go to Jenkins - Configuration
```

There should be Invoke Gradle Script Script. And You can add parameter under "switches". You will tell jenkis to u

```
 -Ptest.folder="src/test/resources/Sanity/"

Tasks = runProdTest
```

You all set !!